# Text align paragraph in rich UITextView with CoreText?

Tags: ios, uitextview, core-text, nsattributedstring, text-alignment

In an iOS 6 application, I have a UITextView set to accept attributed string.

How can I change the text alignement (left - right - center - justified) of paragraphs?

The following code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributeString = [textView.attributedText mutableCopy];

CTTextAlignment alignment = kCTCenterTextAlignment;

CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[] = {kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierAlignment, sizeof(alignment), &alignment};
CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, sizeof(settings) / sizeof(settings[0]));
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)mutableAttributeString, CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)mutableAttributeString)), kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle);
CFRelease(paragraphStyle);

textView.attributedText = mutableAttributeString;
```

crash on the last line with:
-[__NSCFType headIndent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1559b2d0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating and using an NSParagraphStyle instead. (Correspondingly, you should also use `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` for the attribute name, although the behavior suggests that the names are the same.)

NSParagraphStyle is new to iOS in 6. I don't know what to suggest for developers targeting older versions.